# Вместо вывода на экран текста в консоли вижу два пробела

Tags: c++, строки

Где то тут была реклама "Лучше спросить и побыть глупцом 5 минут нежели не спросить и остаться им." У меня вопрос как раз из этой сферы.

Перед новым годом сделал паузу в разрабатываемом проекте (пишу в студии) и наконец добраться до изучения программирования под линуксом. Написал элементарный тестовый код на С++ скомпилировал но вывода не виду... Подскажите что не так ?

Код:

```
#include<iostream>

class Book
{
private:
    int year;
    char* author;
    char* bookName;

public:

    Book(int year, char* author, char* bookName)
    {
        this->year = year;
        this->author = author;
        this->bookName = bookName;
    }

    char* getStr()
    {
        return (char*)(std::to_string(year)+" | "+author+" | "+bookName).c_str();
    }

    int getYear(){return year;}
};


int main()
{
    Book b[] = {Book(2016,(char*)"Me",(char*)"Options..."), Book(2018,(char*)"Me",(char*)"Options VAK...")};    

    for(int i(0);i<2;i++)
        std::cout<<b[i].getStr()<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
LibPrograme: LibPrigrame.o
    g++ -o Programe LibPrigrame.o

LibPrigrame.o: main.cpp
    g++ -o LibPrigrame.o -c main.cpp
```

Компиляция проходит, но вот вместо вывода на экран текста в консоли вижу два пробела... 
Буду благодарен за совет.

Comment: А дело не в Linux. Вы из функции возвращаете указатель на какие-то данные объекта, который существует только внутри функции, а при выходе из функции разрушается. А ещё вы строками неправильно пользуетесь. Используйте `std::string` или вручную копируйте данные в конструкторе и тогда ещё надо память чистить в деструкторе. Раз уж у вас плюсы - возьмите std::string, оставьте эти `char*` сишникам =)

Comment: Я бы вместо гимнастики с указателями посоветовал `std::string`...

Comment: Благодарю всех за советы) понял свою ошибку))

Comment: Заголовок вопроса никаким образом не отражает его содержимого...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Book
{
private:
    int m_year;
    std::string m_author;
    std::string m_bookName;

public:

    Book(int year, const char* author, const char* bookName):
        m_year{year},
        m_author{author},
        m_bookName{bookName}
    {
    }

    std::string getStr()
    {
        return std::to_string(m_year)+" | "+m_author+" | "+m_bookName;
    }

    int getYear(){return m_year;}
};


int main()
{
    Book b[] = {Book(2016,"Me","Options..."),
                Book(2018,"Me","Options VAK...")
               };

    for(int i(0);i<2;i++)
        std::cout<<b[i].getStr()<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Я бы так написал.

Comment: Благодарю Ваш код запустился сразу.

Answer (score 2):

Да тут без разницы Linux или нет...

```
char* getStr()
{
    return (char*)(std::to_string(year)+" | "+author+" | "+bookName).c_str();
}
```

Т.е. создается временная строка `string`, и возвращается указатель на буфер в этой временной строке (или как уж там реализован `c_str()`). Когда вы его используете - самой строки уже нет, так что это указатель в не пойми куда. Вот не пойми что и выводится...

Вы же в С++ работаете? Так работайте со строками С++, а не С - вот так, например: https://ideone.com/PDuXE8

Comment: Да похоже вы правы в этом была ошибка... Я бегло проверил через онлайн компилятор код, онлайн компилытор кстати все верно отобразил (так как задумывалось)

Comment: Да не похоже, а точно :) Кстати, в том же ideone ваш код ничего не выводил.

Comment: Я тут проверял:
http://cpp.sh/7rxu

Он понял что я имел ввиду))